# NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `TIFF\"' aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to use convert from imageMagick to run this command on aws lambda `convert -scene 1 test.tiff output.jpg` to convert a tiff to image .

But I am getting this errors always

```
NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `TIFF\"
```

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version? Does `convert -version` list tiff for a delegate? If not, then libtiff was not installed. Otherwise try: `convert test.tiff -scene 1 output.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem - in my case, `TIFF\"` was failing because of a trailing quote (`"`)